# How to set a specific keyboard inside an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, ios4, internationalization, keyboard

In an iPhone app I want the user to do some input in a different language.
For example the user is an English speaker and has his(or her) device set with the English language. When running my app he(or she) will have to input some French and some Japanese.
Is there a way I can bring the proper keyboard from inside the app without forcing the user to change  his(or her) usual settings. According to what I have read up to now, I am not sure there is a good answer. I still hope.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually pick certain keyboards (numeric, email, etc) from the interface-builder-like aspects of UITextFields, so take a peek at the code options for setting those things. You may be able to pick it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but after reading a few related post, I am not optimistic on finding an easy way. Is there a way I could subclass the standard keyboard and customize it to my needs or something like that?

Comment: I have the same question. Or at least I can detect the ios keyboard selected.

Comment: I think you guys might want to go this route if you need a completely custom keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644552/297472