# new ios6 language keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/ObjC - How to create a custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/iphone-objc-how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard)

Seeing as apple is not planning on implementing a language keyboard for my native language I want to see if perhaps I could create one. Currently I have to disable the auto completion and correction functionality on my iPad and iPhone to allow me to type messages or emails in my native language.

My native language is Afrikaans and there are about 23 million Afrikaans speakers in the world today.

How would one go about creating a new language keyboard for ios6?

Comment: Laat weet hoe jy vorder - ek is self opsoek na 'n opsie om Afrikaans gemaklik te kan gebruik!

Comment: @Ryan sal verseker so maak :)

Comment: Uit nieuwsgierigheid: wat is het verschil met een Nederlands keyboard?

Comment: @onnoweb Baie van die woorde word anders gespel in Afrikaans ;) Nederlands is wel die moedertaal waarvan Afrikaans afkomstig is maar die 350 jaar van aparte groei hier in die Suid punt van Afrika het veroorsaak dat die twee tale net te veel uit sync geraak het. Die grootste voordeel van 'n native language keyboard is die auto completion wat input op die devices baie, baie viniger maak. Snaakse ding is my blackberry het 'n Afrikaanse woordeboek en Afrikaanse autocomplete. Sal graag soortgelyke funksionaliteit op my Apple devices wil kan gebruik...

Comment: It would be great if you speack in english here ...