# Customize the appearance of the iOS keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

How would I go about this? I want to keep all the functionality of the keyboard (spell-checking, being able to change languages, etc), but I want to customize the look and feel of the buttons and the background.

How would I go about this?

Comment: There are various tricks you can play to overlay buttons with other ones.  A popular one is to overlay the "." button on the numeric pad to provide a "Done" key.  And there's probably an opensource project somewhere to provide a DIY keyboard.

Comment: That would probably also be good for a done button. But when you need to do it to all the buttons, and for all the buttons with all the different languages that are out there, then I don't know if it's an option anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you could probably get is by following the tutorial [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html)

Beware, this is a pretty complicated task.

Comment: Might be a solution. Seems quite complicated if you want to replace all the buttons backgrounds in all the different languages though.

Comment: Have we really hit a point where it simply isn't possible to do it?

Comment: Well really, once you have one keyboard, you can just reuse your code (with a few tweaks) over and over for each language that you want.

Answer (score 1):

For simple functionalities you can always use  textfield properties .

[image]

For custom things check [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/iphone-objc-how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard)

and

[This Link](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/)

Comment: It's not really the functionalities I need control over. It's the look and feel of the keyboard. The colors and such.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you for look and background of keyboard

https://github.com/caydenliew/CLKeypad

Comment: Thanks. There's also a github project with a whole keyboard out there, but it doesn't work for multiple languages. That's the big problem.