# Customized iPhone Keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Is it possible to customize the iPhone keyboard without jailbreaking? I'm trying to design an app that would conform to Apple's guidelines, but implements the use of the international keyboard in the same way that emoji uses it. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement a custom keyboard in your app, Like this,
http://a5.mzstatic.com/au/r30/Purple/v4/9a/12/8e/9a128e7d-0e19-2009-1b4f-6cd0ca3a541c/screen568x568.jpeg
Then you can design to whatever you want because it isn't an official iOS keyboard.

Comment: The image link is for an app called Riddle Me This - guess the word.