# How to create custom keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iOS application. I need to create a custom keyboard with malayalam language. Is there any SDK for the same ??

Thank you

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/custom-ios-keyboards try this thirdparty tool study and know how the done

Comment: I think its like [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard).

Comment: would be nice if the people behind [this product](https://www.facebook.com/MalayalamKeyboard) and [this other product](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2010/12/indic-scripts-keyboards-available-for.html) would release their keyboards as SDK's you can take advantage of

Comment: Similar question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard