# what is Best approach to create customize keypad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

how can I create functionality of custom fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

before going to git , try to do it on yourself.
1.create an array(numeric-only) of images[1.img, 2.img,3.png......] or (alphabetic-only) array of images [a.img, b.img, c.img.
2.lets say you want only numeric. (a)take a view say keypadView, (b)Run a loop some thing like .Do something like this in for loop...

```
for(i=0; i<numericArray.count;i++)
```

{

```
    UIButton *numericKeyPadSingleButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17+((i%3)*(104+5)), 67+(height*84), 104, 79)];
    [numericKeyPadSingleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[numericArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [numericKeyPadSingleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(singleNumberClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[numericKeyPadSingleButton setTag:i];
keypadView addSubiew:numericKeyPadSingleButton];
```

}
finaly you can create a Done button also.

then your singleNumberClicked looks like this:

```
-(void)singleNumberClicked:(id)sender
```

{

```
if ([sender tag] == 0) {

    //1 clicked
    }
```

else if ([sender tag] == 1) {

```
    //2 clicked
    }
}
```

you can do it man try your self.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use  https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards library on Github.