# Customized ios keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, customization

I need a customized keyboard. Only certain certain letters should be in the keyboard. I guess this is quite easy. The problem is that I need each tangent to basically contain 2 characters.
Lets say that each letter has a value. So for the letter A that has a value of 1 I also need to display that number in the same tangent. I would be like 70-80% of all the space would be taken by the letter A and (maybe at the bottom, right aligned) there would be a little number.

I guess this is not possible to do by using and customizing the default keyboard right? What would you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

considering you requirements you got nothing to do with the default keyboard...

create a UIView with buttons for the keys and use it wherever you like.

Godd Luck,

Comment: This seem more like a comment then an answer.