# How to reduce the size of iPad on board keyboard?

Tags: ios

I am using My own custom Keyboard  .

It Loading On iPad keyboard.
My Keyboard view having only some keys, So when I load the keyboard all button's size become bigger .

I want to reduce the size of on board Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you want a customized keyboard instead of the standard one.
If so, you may want to take a look at this helpful link:
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/

Apple on creating custom input views:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2

(Referenced from [How to create a custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard))